# HTML 5.00 not supported in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have used the following code for picking a date:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDLP" runat="server" Width="153px" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Everything is okay with this. But while it is rendering with Internet Explorer/ Mozilla, it just shows a textbox.
This must be happened for version conflict of browser or for unsupported features of html.

What is the way to make this tag compatible with all versions of browsers(specially internet Explorer)?

Comment: better use jquery or ajax plugin with textbox control.

Comment: A handy reference, especially if you have to deal with Internet Exploder: https://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: AFAIK, the `<asp:TextBox>` control does not support a `type` property, and also AFAIK it always renders as either an `<input type="text">` or a `<textarea>` element. See here (left column) for which properties it supports, `type` is not listed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.8 Note that *.NET Web Controls* are totally different from HTML elements and it is certainly not possible to 1:1 translate them to each other in any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ASP.NET WebForms, the easiest way of having a TextBox with date selection is by using the [CalendarExtender](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Calendar) control of  [AjaxControlToolkit](https://www.devexpress.com/products/ajax-control-toolkit/).

The library was originally built by Microsoft, but development has been taken over by DevExpress.

NuGet is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/).